# Open Ping between vm's different zones Google Cloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

How do I get 2 vms from different zones to ping? By default I know that icmp is released by default. Anyway I allow icmp in and out in the 2 vms, but it still does not work.
Tks

Comment: Do you have TCP or UDP flows between them? VPC flow logs and firewall runs can show those.

Comment: Firewall rules logging, I meant to say.

Answer (score 0):

I've created two GCE Instances. One in us-east1-b and the other one in europe-west1-b. Then I've created a firewall rule allowing the icmp protocol with priority (1000) using this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#creating_firewall_rules).

Finally I did a ping between the two GCE Instances and it works.

Hope this helps.